# Node.js detect if a variable exists in req for every page a user goes to

Tags: javascript, node.js

More specifically, I have an auth system that uses passportjs and `req.user` is defined if the user is authenticated.

Right now my website only has about 5 pages, but it's growing, and at the top of every route, I check if `req.user` exists and I pass a true or false variable to the rendered template, and the template renders accordingly.

I messed around with things such as `app.get("*")` but I didn't end up finding anything good.

How could I check if `req.user` (or anything else that could exist within `req`...) exists -- when a user goes to any page of my website, without repeting code?

Progress:

Using this code in `app.js`:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // Using req.locals.isAuthenticated would be better, as it's automatically passed to every rendered templates.
  req.context = {};
  req.context.isLoggedIn = req.isAuthenticated();
  // req.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
  next();
});

app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);
```

and this in the `routes/dashboard` route:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('dashboard', { isLoggedIn: req.context.isLoggedIn });
});
```

Works - I can then see if the user is logged in by doing for example `{{ isLoggedIn }}`.

However when I uncomment the req.locals line in the first code snippet, I get a 500 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to note:

- Usually when your application needs to do something for a bunch of different pages, you want to setup a middleware function via [`app.use`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use)
- Express has a [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.locals) variable whose properties will be included in any rendered template

With the above points in mind, you can construct something like the following:

```
app.use(function(res, req, next) {
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = typeof(req.user) !== 'undefined';
  next();
});
```

You then supply your **additional** template variables when your routes call `res.render`.  For example:

```
app.get('/about', function(res, req) {
  res.render('about', { 'testValue': 14} );
});
```

Your template will have access to both `isAuthenticated` and `testValue`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the info. I really want to use req.locals, but I'm having some issues, I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: @DanyP:  It should be `res.locals`, where I had `req.locals`.  I've updated my answer to reflect this change.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you put some middleware in place before your route handlers but after passport's.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    // Create a `context` object for use in any view.
    // This allows the context to grow without impacting too much.
    req.context = {};

    // Assign your flag for authenticated.
    req.context.isAuthenticated = typeof req.user !== 'undefined';

    // Let the next middleware function perform it's processing.
    next();

});
```

Then you can render each view with the context.

```
app.use('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', req.context); // Context is passed to view for usage.
});
```

This is all untested code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, learned from it. I picked the answer with the `res.locals`option simply because it allows me to use the properties on all the rendered page without repeating code.

Comment: I don't blame you, that was a nice post by Tim.  I intend to investigate it more for what I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as is already mentioned here ,but in this case you are going to check completely every request. Maybe you have got / you are going to have some pages that don't require any authentification and in this case you have to make some statement that will skip auth for that particular page or you can use something like this:

```
function checkUser(req, res, next) {
    req.userAuth = (req.user !== undefined);
    next();
}

app.post("settings", checkUser, doSomething);
app.post("administration", checkUser, doSomething);
app.post("index", doSomething); // Doesn't require any authentification
```

Or you can straight a way redirect a user

```
function checkUser(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user === undefined) {
        res.redirect("/login"); // res.render
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that should come in handy for me eventually!